# PHP Selenium WebDriver using sendKeys causes redirect

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a problem trying to submit the form automatically using php-webdriver client, everything went fine until one day my script was no longer able to submit the form. The process of filling form is really simple:

I have my fields that I want to populate in that form and click submit button with attribute `name="submit"`. Everything worked fine but now the same code somehow doesn't cut it.

```
$input = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('first_name'));
$input->sendKeys('Example');

$submit = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('submit'));
$submit->click();
```

This is pretty much what my script does it finds a few fields and sends some values after that I simply click the submit button. After the submission, I checked what response I get using `getPageSource()` method, and surprisingly it showed me different page, but in the right circumstances it should be on the same page. If I delete every line of code that uses `sendKeys()` method then it stays on the same page which is the correct behavior. But I'm not understanding why sendKeys in combination with `$submit->click()` causes something like 'redirect' it redirects to index page which is initial website page and it used to work correctly, I checked everything many times and it looks that I provide all required fields correctly and able to submit the form. But instead of successful form submission response, I see that I'm on the index page.

Maybe there are known issues with this but I'm just not aware of it? Some advice, ways of how could I debug it would be really helpful because now I'm clueless, there's simply no indication of what went wrong.